# Hide UserMenu instead of remove

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to some how hiding the usermenus instead of removing them? 
Right now, I am doing:

```
string currentPage = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.ToString());            

if (currentPage.Equals("Default.aspx"))
{
    UserMenu.Items.Remove(UserMenu.FindItem("FindMerchant"));
    UserMenu.Items.Remove(UserMenu.FindItem("Ladder"));
}
```

But the problem with removing the UserMenu, is that it causes some viewstate issues, when I try to use the search function on the page.
So instead of remove, I need to do something like:

```
UserMenu.Items.hide(UserMenu.FindItem("FindMerchant"));
```

or

```
UserMenu.FindItem("FindMerchant").Visible = False;
```

Notice that it says 'hide' and not remove.

If not it is possible to hide them, is there another way around this?

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days, I finally realized that the problem is caused by calling the method at a wrong place. I called it in the page_init, instead of Page_Load.

I hope this will save someone else for the headaches I've been through.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the CSS-style `display=none;`?

```
UserMenu.FindItem("FindMerchant").Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");
```

Or add a class where `display` is set to `none`:

```
UserMenu.FindItem("FindMerchant").Attributes.Add("class", "invisible");
```

Comment: Hi. I can't seem to do neither.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but maybe using .IsEnabled will be better approach in your case (disregarding the specific question you asked)? 
Most menus show you the full menu and enabling/disabling the menu entries.
It's not exactly solution to your question but maybe worth a thought .